# How time consuming is it to work with multiple TFS collections at the same time

Tags: tfs

As a developer if You had two projects on completely different TFS collections how much of a pain would it be to switch between the two. Ie lets say your coding on both projects in a single day and you want to commit changes to both on most days, would this be a real pain or not so bad?

I.e. is working with code in different collections cause a significant workflow switching cost in a developers day?

I have only worked with one collection so I am not sure what this would be like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collections and the projects contained therein are independent, then it isn't any trouble, as long as you never try to map the same directories to both collections.

It will be the directory mapping that will usually get you in trouble. For instance, if you have mapped your root source directory in one collection's workspace, then any new project in the other collection will have to be placed in a very different directory base. An example: if you have `C:\Source\TFS` as being mapped to `TfsCollectionOne\MegaProject`, when you try to create a new project for working with `TfsCollectionTwo\SomeOtherMajorProject` under `C:\Source\TFS`, you will get code blocked because anything and everything under `C:\Source\TFS\` belongs exclusively to `TfsCollectionOne\MegaProject` until the directory mapping is removed. In cases like that, I end up creating `D:\Source\TFS` on my second HD so I can create additional projects for `TfsCollectionTwo\SomeOtherMajorProject`.

If you need the same code in different TfsCollections, you will need to rethink your source configuration, as that isn't possible.

Comment: This is correct is you consider classic version control (TFVC); these considerations do not apply to Git repositories.
From a developer viewpoint VC is the main gotcha. Work items work seamless but keep in mind that each Collection has its own set of counters, e.g. you get Bug #42 in Collection A, but work item 42 in Collection B is a Tasks. To avoid ambiguity in mails, reports, specify the context.